# How to make an android app reinstall itself with a different package name?

Tags: android, apktool, rooted-device

Assuming rooted access, what's the best way to make an Android app reinstall itself using a different package name?

[GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net) does this to avoid detection by other software. AFAIK, the normal way to do this on a PC is to

1. Decompile the apk using something like apktool.
2. Make changes in the decompiled files.
3. Recompile the apk and sign it.

I'm aware that the apk files for an installed app are present in `/data/app` and can be accessed on a rooted device. My question is, does the app need to automate all of the above steps(making apktool run, modifying decompiled files using something like `sed` and finding a way to sign the recompiled apk on the device) or am I missing a trick somewhere?

Comment: i almost think you won't find an answer here, you might be better off asking on a different community, i don't think you'll find an answer related to code for this here

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's another, simpler way to do this. If there isn't, I'll have to proceed with implementing this method anyway :( Thanks for the response though. I see you're an android developer yourself, what do you think should be a good solution for the above problem?

Comment: i don't have any experience with something like this and i'm not sure how you would find a solution on stack overflow for this as i don't think there would be a coding solution available, which is why i think you might be better off asking on one of the other stack exchange communities, maybe at security or possibly superuser, although i'm just guessing really :)

Comment: if the device is rooted maybe you dont need to resign it, else I don't think you can further optimize your exploit process  :)